# How to listen to mp3 file like synchronous method?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-media-player, wmplib

I'm creating a C# application, in which I need to reproduce a MP3 file. As soon as the file has been completely reproduced (not before) I want execute other methods.

The problem is that, since surely a thread is used for reproduce sounds, all the subsequent actions are executed immediately, without waiting for the complete reproduction of the mp3 file.

The code is:

```
 gioco.playSound(true);

 if (gioco.feedbackNao && naoConnect)
 {
    nao.talkNao("Bravo! Continua così.");
 }
 else if (gioco.feedbackVocale && speech.isFound)
 {
    speech.pronunciaFraseCorretta();
 }

#Class UtilityGame
public void playSound(bool rispostaCorretta)
{
   playerOK = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
   playerOK.URL = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Resources/Sound/ok.mp3";
   playerOK.controls.play();
}
```

So, when I try to execute `playSound` method, at the first line, the next instructions are processed before the sounds ends.

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you want to execute the code -after- the mp3 finished playing. So just would have to bind your "after"-code to an event which will be fired after the mp3 is finished playing (maybe like gioco.SoundFinished or something - have a look into the api).

Comment: because Play run on another thread you should join that thread